# Concatenate strings with literal tab and new line character

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-formatting

I've a tab/space delimited file as:

```
31000BL        50014_10011 
25467BL        50050_10003 
47406BL        50001_10015 
40831BL        50114_10006 
40830BL        50114_10009
```

Two columns. I use a  while loop to read this:

```
while read LINE; do 
    printf "$LINE\n" 
    old=($(echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}')) 
    new=($(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}'))  
    ll=$old'^V<tab>'$new                  #I need to work here.   
    printf "$ll\n" 
done < update_ids.txt
```

The output I'd like is

`31000BL\t50014_10011\n25467BL\t50050_10003\n`

There is a literal tab and new line character. I cannot concatenate or print with tab and/or new line character.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not *quite* sure that I understand correctly, but if you'd just want to make sure that there's a literal tab character between your two columns, you can do that in a single `awk` invocation:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ $1=$1; print }' file >newfile
```

Setting `OFS` on the command line to `\t` sets the output field separator to a tab character.  Using `$1=$1` will force `awk` to re-form the current record, and the subsequent `print` would print it out with whatever whitespace it originally used as delimiter replaced with tabs.

The result is written to `newfile` through the use of a redirection.

Alternatively, use a more explicit `printf()` call:

```
awk '{ printf("%s\t%s\n", $1, $2) }' file >newfile
```

Note that this only handles exactly two columns, whereas the first `awk` program would work with data containing multiple columns, without modification.

Related to the question:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Comment: i think you mean `$0=$0` in the first example.

Comment: @lesmana Do I? That would not cause `awk` to re-form the current record, which means that the value of `OFS` would not be inserted between the fields.

Comment: i learned something new. `$1=$1` causes rewriting of `$0` with `OFS`. here is an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941143 thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The shell `read` command can read into multiple variables. You need to set the `IFS` variable to be a tab, which in bash you do with [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting): `IFS=$'\t'`

For output, the `printf` builtin command is what you want.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r old new; do 
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$old" "$new"
done < update_ids.txt
```

To save tab-separated data into a variable you can do:

```
var=$(printf '%s\t%s\n' "$old" "$new")
# or
printf -v var '%s\t%s\n' "$old" "$new"
# or this quoting disaster
var="$old"$'\t'"$new"
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf